# Merging two tables and concatenating the values using linq

Tags: c#, linq

My table data looks like:

```
    table 1:
 Id   CId   Message
 1     1    E:MMM
 1     1    E:NNN
 1     1    E:OOO
 1     2    E:PPP 
 1     2    E:PPP

table 2:
 Id   CId   Message
 1     1    W:NNN
 1     1    W:OOO
```

After merging two tables using linq my output table should be like:
Result table:

```
 Id   CId    ErMessage              WrMessage
 1     1     E:MMM*E:NNN*E:OOO      W:NNN*W.OOO
 1     2     E:PPP*E:PPP
```

Please help me how to achieve.

Comment: This was asked several times. [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/bradvincent/archive/2008/11/01/linq-cheat-sheet.aspx) is the solution you are looking for. Download it. Keep cheat sheets with you at all times. (You should look into join example)

Comment: I am not getting using joins. Could you please help me on this.

Comment: Ok first tell me how is it possible that you have same ID's for different values in your tables. i.e. Table 1: ID - 1; E:MMM
Table 1: ID - 1; E:NNN
Can we assume that these are different ids?

Comment: I want to group those Id's and concatenate the message.

Comment: It is just an example not actual table.

Comment: The main issue here is grouping. Not joining. This is not very clear from your question so please emphasize this in your Q. Glad you got the good answer form @Michael Samtelaze.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var q =
    from t1 in
        table1.GroupBy(g => g.ID).Select(g => new
        {
            ID = g.Key,
            Message = string.Join("*", g.Select(v => v.Message).ToArray())
        })
    join
        t2 in
        table2.GroupBy(g => g.ID).Select(g => new
        {
            ID = g.Key,
            Message = string.Join("*", g.Select(v => v.Message).ToArray())
        }) on t1.ID equals t2.ID
    select new
    {
        ID = t1.ID,
        ErMessage = t1.Message,
        WrMessage = t2.Message
    };
```

Comment: Michael please look into my question again. I have edited it.

Comment: I am new to linq, can you help in detail?

Comment: Please review my source carefully, (this is not about LINQ it more about thinking), replace g.ID with G.Cid.